# Define function and use as onchange in the select statement instead of directly using .change(function)

Tags: javascript

What is wrong with defining a function and using it as onchange in the select statement instead of directly using .change(function).

I want to use this to display a different combo box :

```
     function MetricLayerShowHide (){           
            var type = $(this).val();
              if( type !==''){
                 $('.content').hide();
                 $('#'+type).show();
              }
      }


<select name="MetricType" id="MetricType" onchange="MetricLayerShowHide();" >
    <option value=CD>CD</option>
     <option value=HT>HT</option>
     <option value=Profile>Profile</option>
  </select>

   <div id="CD" style ="display: none" class ="content">
       <SELECT NAME="LayerList" id="layer1">
      </SELECT>
    </div>
```

instead of

```
         $(function(){
        $('#MetricType').change(function(){
            var type = $(this).val();
              if( type !==''){
                 $('.content').hide();
                 $('#'+type).show();
              }
        });
     });
```

this is working though.

Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: We don't know, because you didn't tell us what you expected to happen and what happened instead. "I want to use this" does not even explicitly mention a problem.

Comment: A new combobox will be displayed if I will use this function. Its not happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `this` no longer is the element when you call the function. You are calling the function in the global context, so `this` will be the `window` object inside the function.

You can use the [`call` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to call the function with the element as context:

```
onchange="MetricLayerShowHide.call(this);"
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/co5ymkyk/

Comment: thats not working . I have changed it to MetricLayerShowHide.call(this);

Comment: @PSDebugger: When I try it, it works. I added a link to a demo.

Comment: yes this is working but http://jsfiddle.net/co5ymkyk/1/ is not as in my case I am trying to replace this type of function. what is wrong in this one.

Comment: You should edit your answer and put the JSFiddle there.

Comment: @PSDebugger If you need to update your question to clarify, then update it. Otherwise, the answers will not make sense to you and  others trying to help you.

Comment: @PSDebugger: You are missing a closing bracket for the `if` statement in that fiddle. In the code that you posted in the question it's not missing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is simple: `this` is no longer referring to the element you are expecting when you call the function.

HTML:

```
<form>
    <select name="MetricType" id="MetricType" >
    <option value=CD>CD</option>
    <option value=HT>HT</option>
    <option value=Profile>Profile</option>
</select>
</form>

<div class="content" id="CD">CD</div>
<div class="content" id="HT">HT</div>
<div class="content" id="Profile">Profile</div>
```

Script:

```
$(function(){
        $('#MetricType').change(function(){
           var type = $(this).val();
              if( type !==''){
                 $('.content').hide();
                 $('#'+type).show();

              }});
     });
```

CSS:

```
.content { display: none; }
```

JSFiddle demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/co5ymkyk/6/).

On a side note, this is based on the JSFiddle you posted as a comment. You created a new issue by missing a bracket.

Please update your question, as this answer doesn't make sense out of context. @Guffa actually answered your question correctly.